# Angular 9 nested routes (3 levels)

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9, angular-router

I have nested routes with 3 levels.

Level: 1

```
const MAIN_ROUTE: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: AppComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'events',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/modules/event/event.module').then(m => m.EventModule),
  },
];
..
RouterModule.forRoot(MAIN_ROUTE);
```

Level: 2

```
const EVENT_ROUTE: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EventComponent,
    children: {
           path: 'center',
           loadChildren: () => import('../app/modules/center/center.module').then(m => m.CenterModule),
    }
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redircectTo: '/events/center'
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
..
RouterModule.forChild(EVENT_ROUTE);
```

Level: 3

```
const CENTER_ROUTE: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CenterComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redircectTo: ''
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
..
RouterModule.forChild(CENTER_ROUTE);
```

I have page setup as following:

```
<app-main>
    <some-content></some-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-main>

<app-event>
    <some-content></some-content>
    <router-outlet name="event"></router-outlet>
</app-event>

<app-center>
    <some-content></some-content>
    <router-outlet name="center"></router-outlet>
</app-center>
```

Whenever I navigate to `/events/center`, I don't see the content of `CenterComponent`. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing no content is there is no matching route in your routing modules. If your intent is to provide for multiple named outlets, you must set up a route with a matching `outlet` property.

The following example is from [this article about using multiple outlets.](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/)

```
// use in template
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>  

// routing-module
{
   path: "",
   component: SidebarComponent,
   outlet: "sidebar"  <<<<<<< add this to resolve named routes
}
```

Named routes can be useful but they get complex really fast and can create some *wacky* URIs. Strongly suggest trying to architect your app to keep the number of named routes to a minimum (if possible).

Comment: It's my silly mistake. :D Had explicitly specified named route but config didn't have it. I agree with your point on named route. Thx for pointing out.